# ArchUnit case insensitive name matching

Tags: kotlin, archunit

I'm trying to setup tests with Arch Unit to test my naming conventions, following the [official examples](https://github.com/TNG/ArchUnit-Examples/blob/master/example-junit5/src/test/java/com/tngtech/archunit/exampletest/junit5/NamingConventionTest.java).

It seems ArchUnit's naming assertions are case sensitive, which is bothering me.

I want to test that no classes in the package `domain.service` contains the word `service`.

Given a class `domain.service.FileSystemService`:

- This test passes:

```
 @ArchTest
  val domain_service_should_not_have_names_containing_service: ArchRule =
    noClasses()
      .that().resideInAPackage("..domain.service..")
      .should().haveSimpleNameContaining("service")
```

- This test fails:

```
 @ArchTest
  val domain_service_should_not_have_names_containing_service: ArchRule =
    noClasses()
      .that().resideInAPackage("..domain.service..")
      .should().haveSimpleNameContaining("Service")
```

Am I missing something? Is there a way to make ArchUnit's comparisons case insensitive?

Comment: You may be able to use the option `haveNameMatching()` to match based on Regex

Comment: Yes indeed i thought about that. It adds complexity though because `haveNameMatching` matches on the fully qualified name instead of the simple name.

Comment: Not sure if it works for you, but you could set the regex to check what if name ends with service (or use the ending with method), which is usually the naming convention used anyway

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `haveNameMatching` as proposed in the comments you can also create your own `ArchCondition`s.

```
  public static ArchCondition<JavaClass> containName(String namePart) {
      return new NameContains(namePart);
  }

  private static class NameContains extends ArchCondition<JavaClass> {
      private String namePart;

      NameContains(String namePart) {
          super("contain '" + namePart + "' in the name");
          this.namePart = namePart;
      }

      @Override
      public void check(JavaClass javaClass, ConditionEvents events) {
          boolean containsName = javaClass.getSimpleName().toLowerCase().contains(namePart.toLowerCase());
          String message;

          if (containsName) {
              message = createCheckMessage(javaClass, "contains '" + namePart + "' in the name");
          } else {
              message = createCheckMessage(javaClass, "does not contain '" + namePart + "' in the name");
          }

          events.add(new SimpleConditionEvent(javaClass, containsName, message));
      }
  }

  // taken from com.tngtech.archunit.lang.conditions.ArchConditions
  public static <T extends HasDescription & HasSourceCodeLocation> String createCheckMessage(T object,
          String message) {
      return object.getDescription() + " " + message + " in " + object.getSourceCodeLocation();
  }
```

You can use it like this:

```
  rules.add(noClasses().that().resideInAPackage("..domain.service..").should(containName("Service")));
```

Comment: if condition is satisfied javaClass.getSimpleName().toLowerCase().contains(namePart.toLowerCase())
why you are passing "false" as second parameter to
new SimpleConditionEvent(javaClass, false, message)

it should be 
new SimpleConditionEvent(javaClass, true, message)

Comment: @BartekK: You are right, the code was misleading. I adjusted the code so that it can be used both for `classes()` and `noClasses()`. The asker wanted to identify classes that do not contain a certain name.